# dispatch Event does not execute

Tags: javascript, automation

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('D(b) Pos(r) Expand')[5].click();


var message = document.getElementById('u1109464099');
var emojii = document.getElementById('emoji-picker-trigger');
emojii.click();

var grinsen = document.getElementsByClassName('emoji-picker__emoji')[1].click();


var keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: "Enter"});

var grinsen = document.getElementsByClassName('emoji-picker__emoji')[1].click();


document.getElementById('u1109464099').dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
```

If I execute the script, it won´t enter eventKey "Enter".
It only returns "true" on the Chrome Console. Why? I thought dispatch event was to enter keys in browser?

Comment: You can't emulate key strokes on the keyboard in JS. `dispatchEvent` only triggers an event, it doesn't execute an action which causes an event.

Comment: is there no way to make something like keyenter?

Comment: That depends on what do you actually want to do, and with which element(s).